# Function argument seems to disappear in type analysis

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to make a function generic by using typeclasses, and I keep bumping into this error :

I have a data type :

```hs
data ValeurM m = VLitteralM Litteral
               | VFonctionM (ValeurM m -> m (ValeurM m))
```

which represents either a function or a litteral value, the `m` is a Monad type

I also have an injector class to inject values into this type

```hs
class Injectable m t where
    injecte :: t -> ValeurM m

instance Injectable m Bool where
    injecte = VLitteralM . Bool

instance Injectable m Integer where
    injecte = VLitteralM . Entier
```

I've then tried to make an ifthenelse function in a generic way, like this :

```hs
injIf :: (Fail.MonadFail m) => (Bool -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m) -> ValeurM m
injIf = injecte

ifM :: (Fail.MonadFail m) => Bool -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m
ifM bool iss1 iss2 = if bool then iss1
                             else iss2

ifthenelseM :: (Fail.MonadFail m) => ValeurM m
ifthenelseM = injIf ifM
```

However, I get this error message :

```sh
Interprete.hs:595:9: error:
    • Could not deduce (Injectable
                          m (ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m))
        arising from a use of ‘injecte’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
      from the context: Fail.MonadFail m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   injIf :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                            Fail.MonadFail m =>
                            (Bool -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m) -> ValeurM m
        at Interprete.hs:594:1-89
    • In the expression: injecte
      In an equation for ‘injIf’: injIf = injecte
    |
595 | injIf = injecte
    |         ^^^^^^^
```

It's supposed to resemble [Normalisation by evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalisation_by_evaluation), but I can't seem to make it work

What bothers me is that the error message does not seem to take into account the first Bool parameter, am I missing anything ?

It fails on compilation

Comment: I can not reproduce: I get the expected error `Could not deduce (Injectable m (Bool -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m))` mentioning `Bool` as well.

Comment: Seems strange, how come you get the `Bool`and not I ?

Comment: Maybe you have other instances? Post a full file reproducing the error.

Comment: Can you please post something that's both minimal _and_ complete (i.e., a [MCVE]).

Comment: It does not compile  since the parser module is missing. A minimal complete example would help. Try to remove everything which is not needed and obtain a small file which compiles on its own and exhibits the error.

Comment: @chi full files, normally cropped to essentials only are online :)

Comment: As chi suspected, in the "Q38" section of the first file there is an `instance (Monad m, Injectable m t) => Injectable m (Bool -> t)`. That matches the type you are trying to use `injecte` on (with `t ~ ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m`), which explains why `Bool` isn't showing up in the type error.

Comment: @duplode any idea on how to solve that ? I have to use that instance for the rest... Do I have to create another instance ?

Comment: @olirwin Yup -- Li-yao Xia's answer lays down your options with respect to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This instance

```
instance (Monad m, Injectable m t) => Injectable m ((Bool -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m) -> t) where
    injecte = injecte
```

is not what you want. Indeed, it gives you:

```
injecte :: ((Bool -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m) -> t) -> ValeurM m
```

but you want

```
injIf :: (Bool -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m) -> ValeurM m
```

so instead it's the `Bool -> t` instance which kicks in.

You might need an instance

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (_TODO_)
  => Injectable m (Bool -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m -> ValeurM m) where
```

that overlaps with `Injectable m (Bool -> t)` which is why I added the `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` annotation.

Alternatively, maybe you want a different combination of instances, which would work in combination with the `Injectable m (Bool -> t)` instance

```
instance Injectable m t => Injectable m (ValeurM m -> t) where
instance Injectable m (ValeurM m) where  -- base case
```

Actually, that one seems a better solution. Here's an implementation of these two instances; with this, I could make your code compile:

```
instance (Monad m, Injectable m t) => Injectable m (ValeurM m -> t) where
    injecte f = VFonctionM (\v -> pure (injecte (f v)))

instance (Monad m) => Injectable m (ValeurM m) where
    injecte = id
```

Comment: I can't quite seem to grasp what to put in the `where` clause (on the overlapping example). On the only instances for functions I wrote, there was only one parameter, however here there are three parameters... I've tried using the same template as the one I used for the one parameter functions, but it does not work

Comment: Well, given that this is for a course, that is most likely not what is expected anyway, and the latter solution might be closer to it.

Comment: I must admit I didn't quite understand the latter. I'm only a beginner in this sort of programming and lockdown made it difficult to get in touch with uni teachers

Comment: I think I understand a bit better how this all works, thank you !